# Formal format of .desktop files

Tags: .desktop

I am looking for a formal definition of a .desktop file. I find plenty of tutorials that show examples, but nothing that defines it formally.

Where I can find specifications for `.desktop` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desktop Entry Specification can be found at

https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/index.html